# Android Studio's Play button is not enabled

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am completely new to flutter. I am trying to build https://github.com/flutter/udacity-course/tree/master/course/02_category_widget/task_02_category_widget but the Play Button won't enable.

I tried creating an APK of the project from the command line:

```
flutter build apk
```

and

```
flutter install
```

It creates an APK and runs on my Android device. I also tried creating a new Flutter Project and the Play button is working well on that. What am I missing in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check by running `flutter doctor` if you have everything installed
2. Check that Android Studio knows where your Flutter SDK is located. File->Settings->Languages and Frameworks->Flutter

[image]

Comment: Looks like this solved the issue. Will accept this as the answer. By the way, when I create a new Flutter Project, I did not have to do this. Everything works perfect. Do you know why?

Comment: Not sure, suppose this is a bug of Intellij. There are a couple of tickets regarding this, but I guess this isn't fixed under all conditions yet https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/739